# What is the closed form sum of the series $(1-\frac12)+(\frac13-\frac14)(1-\frac12+\frac13)+(\frac15 - \frac16)(1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14 \frac15)+…$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the closed form sum of this series?

$(1 - \frac12)+(\frac13 - \frac14)(1 - \frac12 + \frac13)+(\frac15 - \frac16)(1 - \frac12 + \frac13 - \frac14 + \frac15)+(\frac17 - \frac18)(1 - \frac12 + \frac13 - \frac14 + \frac15 - \frac16 + \frac17)+...$

I have been working on this infinite series (and other similar series). Wolfram doesn't know and I don't have any other mathematical software so I worked out an answer but I'm not sure if it is correct. Therefore I would like to see what answer anyone else can get to compare.

Also I would like to see some alternative proofs even if my answer is right because my proof was geometric and involved a lot of drawing!

Comment: Would you please share your answer?

Comment: @JonasMeyer (π^2)/24 + ((ln2)^2)/2

Comment: @KingChem Would you please share your geometric argument?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like it's given by
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\ldots\right)^2 - \left(1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}+\ldots\right)\right]+\left(1+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{25}+\ldots\right).
$$
That is, it contains just the off-diagonal terms from the square of the series for $\ln(1+x)$ (evaluated at $x=1$), plus the odd diagonal terms.  This evaluates to
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\ln 2\right)^2-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right]+\frac{\pi^2}{8}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln 2\right)^2+\frac{\pi^2}{24},
$$
in agreement with your result.

Comment: Thanks. Is this a general way to sum series of this type?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean by "series of this type"... if there's a specific family you're working on, you could make a question about it.

Comment: I'm sorry to be so vague, the problem is my lack of knowledge makes me unable to say what kind of series I'm talking about specifically. I'll give it a try. The type of series that have term coefficients that are partial sums?